# Zero/First order Bessel function (of first kind) identity proof

Tags: gamma-function, bessel-functions

Here's my attempt to establish that $\dfrac{d}{dx}J_0(x)=-J_1(x)$:
$$\begin{align*}
J_0(x)&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k! \Gamma(k+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}\\\\
\frac{d}{dx}J_0(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum\cdots\right]\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\Gamma(k+1)}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k}\right]\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!\Gamma(k+1)}2k\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k-1}\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!\Gamma(k+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k-1}\\\\
&=\sum_{p+1=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{p+1}}{((p+1)-1)!\Gamma((p+1)+1)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2(p+1)-1}\\\\
&=-\sum_{p=-1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{p}}{p!\Gamma(p+2)}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2p+1}
\end{align*}$$
Regarding the last step, how can I show that the $-1$-th term of the series is $0$? Considering the plot of the gamma function, I figured I could say something along the lines of $p!=\Gamma(p+1)\to+\infty$ as $p\to-1^+$, but I have this gut feeling that this sort of reasoning wouldn't hold up.

Comment: In general, $J'_k(x)~=~\dfrac{J_{k-1}(x)-J_{k+1}(x)}2~=~\dfrac kx~J_k(x)-J_{k+1}(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first term of the $J_0$ series is a constant, so its derivative is zero, and hence your sum actually starts at $k=1$ before you reindex it.

Comment: Got it. So the limit-reasoning indeed doesn't hold up?

Comment: @user170231 It is true that $1/\Gamma(z)$ has zeros at non-positive integers, which you can prove by integrating the definition by parts.